# Visiting multiple folders with extensions

Tags: python, glob

I'm working on something here, and I'm completely confused. Basically, I have the script in my directory, and that script has to run on multiple folders with a particular extension. Right now, I have it up and running on a single folder. Here's the structure, I have a main folder say, Python, inside that I have multiple folders all with the same .ext, and inside each sub-folder I again have few folders, inside which I have the working file.
Now, I want the script to visit the whole path say, we are inside the main folder 'python', inside which we have folder1.ext->sub-folder1->working-file, come out of this again go back to the main folder 'Python' and start visiting the second directory.
Now there are so many things in my head, the glob module, os.walk, or the for loop. I'm getting the logic wrong. I desperately need some help.

Say, Path=r'\path1'

How do I start about? Would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't got much, here's what I have: Path = os.getcwd()
count = 0
os.chdir(Path + "\\*.ext1"), I think I need to put the os.chdir in a loop so that, it keeps on iterating. Is there, any other way?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/775231/directory-walker-for-python

Comment: Also, you can use ``os.path.split`` to extract the file extension (and take only the ones that you want).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but this main function with a recursive helper function gets a dictionary of all of the files in a main directory:

```
import os, os.path

def getFiles(path):
    '''Gets all of the files in a directory'''
    sub = os.listdir(path)
    paths = {}
    for p in sub:
        print p
            pDir = os.path.join(path, p)
        if os.path.isdir(pDir): 
            paths.update(getAllFiles(pDir, paths))
        else:
            paths[p] = pDir
    return paths

def getAllFiles(mainPath, paths = {}):
    '''Helper function for getFiles(path)'''
    subPaths = os.listdir(mainPath)
    for path in subPaths:
        pathDir = os.path.join(path, p)
        if os.path.isdir(pathDir):
            paths.update(getAllFiles(pathDir, paths))
        else:
                paths[path] = pathDir
    return paths
```

This returns a dictionary of the form `{'my_file.txt': 'C:\User\Example\my_file.txt', ...}`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you distinguish first level directories from its sub-directories, you could do something like this:

```
# this is a generator to get all first level directories
dirs = (d for d in os.listdir(my_path) if os.path.isdir(d)
        and os.path.splitext(d)[-1] == my_ext)

for d in dirs:
    for root, sub_dirs, files in os.walk(d):
        for f in files:
            # call your script on each file f
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Formic](http://www.aviser.asia/formic) (disclosure: I am the author). Formic allows you to specify one multi-directory glob to match your files so eliminating directory walking:

```
import formic
fileset = formic.FileSet(include="*.ext/*/working-file", directory=r"path1")

for file_name in fileset:
    # Do something with file_name
```

A couple of points to note:

- `/*/` matches every subdirectory, while `/**/` recursively descends into every subdirectory, their subdirectories and so on. Some options:

  - If the working file is precisely one directory below your `*.ext`, then use `/*/`
  - If the working file is at any depth under `*.ext`, then use `/**/` instead.
  - If the working file is *at least* one directory, then you might use `/*/**/`
- Formic starts searching in the current working directory. If this is the correct directory, you can omit the `directory=r"path1"`
- I am assuming the working file is literally called `working-file`. If not, substitute a glob that matches it, like `*.sh` or `script-*`.